# How to compute $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to compute ?
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8}$$
I feel the limit is $0$ buy I'm uncertain how to show that.

Comment: That's a classic counterexample: the limit along **every** straight line is 0, but the overall limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 11):

Setting $y = \sqrt{x}$, we obtain:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3}{x^2+x^4} = \frac{x}{1+x^2} = 0$

Setting $y = \sqrt[4]{x}$, we obtain:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2+x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$

For the limit to exist, it can only take on a unique value. Thus, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

we have
$f(y^4,y)=\frac{1}{2}$

and
$f(2y^4,y)=\frac{2}{17}$

so when $y$ tends to zero,
we have two values.
the limit doesn't exist.